# Can Java reuse non-disposed system GUI resources?

Tags: java, user-interface, memory-management, garbage-collection, dispose

I'm trying to understand more about the [dispose()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) function of AWT/Swing's [Window](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) class and what it does.  Imagine the following series of events:

1. An instance A of a Window derivative X is garbage-collected after going out of scope.  Dispose is *not* called prior to garbage collection.
2. A new instance of X, B is created and shown.

**Does B use the non-disposed resources left behind after A was GC'd?**

Furthermore, for a Window derivative Z, if there are many instances of Z, is the JRE able to reuse window resources between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more from a general understanding of how memory works but:

If the resources haven't been disposed of, you can't use them because they are still being taken up. When resources are not disposed/garbage collected/freed they are not usable because there is something else using up that memory. However, once it goes out of scope, it should in fact be disposed of. If it isn't, then that is a but in the JVM that would result in a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

For the second part, if you mean blocks of memory between items, it is all dependent on whether or not there is enough room. Again, I'm not 100% on how the JVM manages memory, but if you need two blocks of memory and there is only one block between `Z1` and `Z2` then no, it would need a contiguous space in memory.